# In a Completely regular $T_1$ space, two disjoint sets, one compact, the other closed, can be separated by a continuous function?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, separation-axioms

Let $X$ be a completely regular $T_1$ space and let $A,B$ be disjoint closed subsets of $X$, where $A$ is compact also. Then is it true that there exist a continuous function $f\colon X \to [0,1]$ such that $f(A)=\{0\}$, $f(B)=\{1\}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT: Take for every $a$ in $A$ a continuous function $f_a\colon X \to [0,1]$ such that $f_a(a) = 0$ and $f_a\ _{|B} = 1$. The open subsets $U_a \colon = f_a^{-1}([0, \frac{1}{2}))$ form an open cover of the compact subset $A$ so there exist finitely many $a_1$, $\ldots, a_m $ so that $\cup_{i=1}^m U_{a_i}$ cover $A$. Consider the continous function $g\, \colon= \min (f_1, \ldots, f_m)$. It take values in $[0,1]$, is $< \frac{1}{2}$ on $A$ and takes value $1$ on $B$. We are almost done. Compose $g$ with a function $\phi$ from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ that is $0$ on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and $1$ at $1$ ( say $\phi(t) = \max \{ 0, 2t-1 \}$ ) to get $f= \phi \circ g$ that separates $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I call gratuitous use of the axiom of choice here. Rather than picking an $f_a$ for every $a$, let the open cover consist of sets $f^{-1}([0,1))$ over all continuous functions $f$ such that $f(B)\subseteq\{1\}$. Complete regularity ensures this is a cover.

Comment: @Mario Carneiro: How would you have liked this result presented to you when you were learning general topology?

Comment: @orangeskid : How do you take $f_a(a)=a$ ? $a$ is not in $[0,1]$ ..

Comment: @Saun Dev: Ah, good catch, should be $0$.

Comment: @orangeskid Gratuitous AC is a pet peeve of mine. I don't think it complexifies the proof at all, and it is more clear to me, at least - you are creating an open cover, so just define the property of being in the cover and prove it is a cover and you're done. Alternatively, more along the lines of your current proof, you could also take *all* valid $f_a$ functions (that is, functions satisfying the hypotheses on $f_a$) and use the $U_a$ so generated, rather than just picking one for each $a$.

Comment: @Mario Carneiro: It is a totally correct call from you. :-).  For me was more like retracing steps of a proof that I've seen a while ago.

Comment: @orangeskid : Shouldn't we have $\phi(t)=\max \{0,2t-1\}$ ?